# Should std::end for strings point past null terminator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I've noticed that `std::end` will always refer to the null terminator when it comes to strings or character arrays. I thought that `std::end` was supposed to refer to the end of an array following the last valid element. Is `'\0'` not considered a valid element? It's part of the array. Here are some tests that all return true:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s("hello!");
    auto s_end = *(s.data() + s.size() + 1);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha  << (*std::end(s) == s_end) << "\n"
              << (s_end == '\0') << "\n";
    char buf[6 + 1];
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), &buf[0]);
    auto buf_end = *(buf + s.size() + 1);
    std::cout << (*std::end(buf) == buf_end) << "\n"
              << (buf_end == '\0') << "\n";

    char test[3] = {'h', '\0', 'e'};
    std::cout << (*std::end(test) == '\0');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `end` iterator is not dereferenceable. By dereferencing it, your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: The null terminator is not part of what is considered to be stored in `std::string`. For example, it's not included in `size()` and not returned by `back()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a character array, `std::end` indeed points past the last character in the array. For

```
char test[3] = {'h', '\0', 'e'};
```

the pointer `std::end(test)` is the same as `test + 3`. Dereferencing it is the same as evaluating `test[3]`. This is undefined behaviour. In your particular case it just happened that it yielded `'\0'`. But in general it might yield a different value, or crash, or something else entirely. `std::end(test)` does **not** point to the `'\0'` character at index 1 in the array `test`!

Note that `std::end` behaves uniformly with respect to all arrays. That is, if we have an array `T a[N]`, then `std::end(a)` returns `a + N`, regardless of whether `T` is `char` or what the content of `a` is. It doesn't give you the end of the string; it gives you the end of the array. Again, the return value is always `a + N`. No exceptions!

For `std::string`, there is a terminating null character, but it's not considered part of the string. (Unlike the other characters, you're not allowed to modify it, on pain of undefined behaviour.) If you have

```
std::string s("hello");
```

then `s[5]` will have the value of the null character, but as I said, it's not considered part of the string: `s` is considered to have five characters, not six. It's best to think of `std::string` as not being null-terminated at all. The last character is `s[4]` which has value `'o'`, and `std::end(s)` is the iterator just past `std::begin(s) + 4`, that is, `std::begin(s) + 5`.

This is a bit more subtle than it looks, as the standard doesn't technically guarantee that `std::end(s)` is dereferenceable at all, so you can't necessarily say that it points to the terminating null. In practice, it does point to the terminating null, but dereferencing it is still undefined behaviour.

Comment: According to the C++11 standard and onward it just cannot be undefined behaviour in regards to std::string (yes, it's messy). It does technically guarantees that it's deferenceable for std::string. std::string has now the very defined behaviour of requiring to be continuous and contain a null character at the end. `std::string.begin()`, `std::string.data()`, `std::string.c_str()`,  and  `&std::string[0]`, all point to the same place according to the rules.
So there is a conflict in the language definition between general rules for end and string.